# Apparmor problem with ecryptfs mount on mysql folder

Tags: mysql, ecryptfs, apparmor

I am getting `mysql` to run on a `ecryptfs` filesystem in a standard LAMP stack running in DigitalOcean Ubuntu 18.04.2 for a Wordpress website.

It is running well with the process below, except that AppArmor needs to be disabled for MySQL to start (on the `ecryptfs` mount), and as I am running CIVICRM on Wordpress, there still are quirky behaviours relating to queries on the database that is not responded well.  However, overall at this stage, WP is up and running.  The process I've used below is to make a copy of the `mysql` folder into a `ecrypfs` folder and bind mount it back to `/var/lib/mysql` to sidestep changes in `my.cnf` and `apparmor`. <strike>However, `mysql` still refuse to start until I remove the `apparmor` profile for mysql.</strike>

1. install `ecryptfs`

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install ecryptfs-utils
   ```
2. stop `mysql` service

   ```
   sudo service mysql stop
   ```
3. make the encrypted folder

   ```
   sudo mkdir /usr/local/enc/mysql
   ```
4. rename the current `mysql` folder

   ```
   sudo cd /var/lib
   sudo mv mysql mysql.bak
   ```
5. mount encrypted folder onto `mysql` folder

   ```
   sudo mount -t ecryptfs /usr/local/enc/mysql /var/lib/mysql
   ```

   There will be questions asked, I have taken the default `[1,1,n,n,yes]`

   Or, you can add do a automount add the following line via nano /etc/fstab, but the password will need to be here as well which is not secure:

   `/usr/local/enc/mysql /var/lib/mysql ecryptfs key=passphrase:passwd=xxxxxxxx,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_passthrough=n,ecryptfs_enable_filename_crypto=n 0 0`
6. copy all contents with their permission from current `mysql` folder to the encrypted folder

   ```
   sudo cp -R -p /var/lib/mysql.bak /var/lib/mysql
   ```
7. move the content in `/var/lib/mysql` 1 level up

   ```
   sudo cd /var/lib/mysql
   sudo mv mysql.bak/* .
   sudo rmdir mysql.bak
   ```
8. at this point you can check that files are in clear in `/var/lib/mysql` but the associated files in `/usr/local/enc/mysql` are gibberish/encrypted
9. try to restart `mysql`, only to be met with error

   ```
   sudo service mysql start

   Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
   See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
   ```

<strike>10. After checking that all permissions of the 2 folders are correct, I tried disabling `apparmor` for mysql with following steps</strike>

```
    sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld /etc/apparmor.d/disable/
    sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
```

10. Add the encrypted folder as alias into apparmor

    ```
    sudo nano /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/alias

    add this line to the file:
    alias /var/lib/mysql -> /usr/local/enc/mysql/,
    ```
11. And `mysql` can start now, my Wordpress works too

    ```
    sudo service mysql start
    ```

<strike>However, I am still keen to get Apparmor working right rather than disabling the mysql profile.  Any advise on how this can be done?</strike>

Answer (score 0):

I did some more digging and I think i got the answer.  Despite what i saw from some posts that apparmor does not care about the mount source folder, apparantly it does look to where the source folder is from when doing the mount.  this is actually good security.  i tried adding the source folder as an alias in apparmor and it now works.  i have also change the mount to automount.  the quirk that I last described also went away.  I will edit my orginal post for these points.

A follow up question I have now is the performance for having ecryptfs supporting mysql, any pointers for this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My experience with AppArmor, mysql, and encryptfs, is you must alias BOTH the source bits, and the mounted bits in

/etc/apparmor.d/tunables/alias

```
alias /var/lib/mysql/ -> /usr/local/encrypted-source/mysql/,
alias /var/lib/mysql/ -> /usr/local/encrypted/mysql/,
```

Note this is Ubuntu 20.04

Have a look in /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld and a lot became evident when looking there.